# How to label point features with alphanumeric labels. Only allowing numbers?

Tags: qgis, labeling, point, features, mapping

New to QGIS. Using point features as markers on a map imported from Google Earth. In my first shapefile layer the alphanumeric labelling worked fine. Added in a second layer and it is only allowing numerical labels? I noticed under layer properties, on the labels tab, the value is shown as 123 Labels (i.e. numeric), whereas for my other layer, the value is shown as abc Labels. Cannnot work out how to correct this?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to label a column called "Labels" but the data type is NUMERIC (the 123).. .is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new field in QGIS using the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html) (via view attribute table) and state you want a text column
(limited to 50 characters here but that depends on your source.)

You can also calculate the new field with the existing numeric field.

[image]